# Why row from DB is not deleted when many-to-many relationship in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have many-to many relationship in my Spring Boot application. I need to create "favourites" feature with Users and Ads. User can favourite many ads, also ads can be favourited by many Users. This is relation between them:

User class:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_ads",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ads_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Ads> adsFavourites = new HashSet<Ads>();
```

This is Ads class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "adsFavourites")
    private Set<JwtUser> userFavourites = new HashSet<JwtUser>();
```

This is Controller class:

```
@DeleteMapping("users/favourites/delete")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteUserFavourite(@RequestHeader("Authorization")String token, @RequestParam(required = true) Long userId, @RequestParam(required=true) Long adsId) throws NotFoundException, ForbiddenException {
        jwtUserServiceImplement.deleteFavourite(userId, token, adsId);
        if (jwtUserServiceImplement.isDeleted) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("OK", HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Not Found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

And this is UserServiceImplementation:

```
  @Override
    public void deleteFavourite(Long userId, String token, Long adsId) throws ForbiddenException {
        JwtUser jwtUser = jwtRepository.findOneById(userId);
        if (jwtUser != null) {
            for (Ads ads : jwtUser.getAdsFavourites()) {
                if (ads.getId().equals(adsId)) {
                    jwtUser.getAdsFavourites().remove(ads);
                    isDeleted = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }
        
    }
```

For inserting favourite, User needs to click on ads, and that functionality is working fine. Also, I can send list of all ads which are favourited by the User. But when I want to delete some add from User's favourites(User wants to remove ad from his favourites) I can't do it. Methods are executed okay, Postman returns OK satus, but row from DB is not deleted. Just to say that I only want to delete ads from User's list, not vice versa.(All logic needs to be done from User's point of view, not from ads). Can someone helps me?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. Use a debugger. Sorry to sound condescending but you should always know what your application is doing. Along those lines enable the SQL output, .e.g. `spring.jpa.show-sql=true`.

1 Don't instantiate a `Collection` in your entity class. This property is for query results. When you want to write a relationship, create the set or query the existing set. Remove the `new HashSet<Ads>()` in your code and you'll get the dreaded `LazyInitializationExcetion` which is your clue for part 2.

```
   private Set<Ads> adsFavourites;
```

2 Relations are not instantiated by the default `Repository` queries, or at least not for `ManyToMany` relationships. You need to make your own query to specifically read them.

```
@Query("from JwtUser u left join fetch u.adsFavourites where u.id=:id")
JwtUser findByIdJoinAds(@Param("id") Long id);
```

3 In spring-data-jpa an entity is detached after a query, though admittedly I'm a little fuzzy on this. I needed to do `save` after altering the `adsFavourites` set. Probably because `ManyToMany` relationships need a join table.

```
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    write();
    read();
    delete();
    read();
}

@Autowired
JwtUserRepository jwtRepository;
@Autowired
AdsRepository adsRepository;

private void delete() {
    System.out.println("delete");
    JwtUser jwtUser = jwtRepository.findByIdJoinAds(1L);
    for (Ads ads : jwtUser.getAdsFavourites()) {
        if (ads.getId().equals(1L)) {
            jwtUser.getAdsFavourites().remove(ads);
            break;
        }
    }
    jwtRepository.save(jwtUser);
}

private void read() {
    System.out.println("read");
    System.out.println( jwtRepository.findByIdJoinAds(1L) );
}

private void write() {
    System.out.println("write");
    JwtUser user = new JwtUser();
    
    Ads ads1 = new Ads();
    adsRepository.save(ads1);

    Ads ads2 = new Ads();
    adsRepository.save(ads2);
    
    Set<Ads> ads = new HashSet<>();
    ads.add(ads1);
    ads.add(ads2);
    user.setAdsFavourites(ads);
    
    jwtRepository.save(user);
    
}
```

Which gives me:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists ads CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists jwt_user CASCADE 
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_ads CASCADE 
Hibernate: create table ads (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table jwt_user (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table user_ads (user_id bigint not null, ads_id bigint not null, primary key (user_id, ads_id))
Hibernate: alter table user_ads add constraint FKjo0u9wqmq7jkp7ovwxg5pebec foreign key (ads_id) references ads
Hibernate: alter table user_ads add constraint FK2tmldht7773rpej1o6nfyfmr foreign key (user_id) references jwt_user
2020-06-20 22:45:37.451  INFO 3048 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-06-20 22:45:37.457  INFO 3048 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-20 22:45:37.629  INFO 3048 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-06-20 22:45:37.634  INFO 3048 --- [           main] c.m.ManytomanytestApplication            : Started ManytomanytestApplication in 1.704 seconds (JVM running for 2.136)
write
Hibernate: insert into ads (id) values (null)
Hibernate: insert into ads (id) values (null)
Hibernate: insert into jwt_user (id) values (null)
Hibernate: insert into user_ads (user_id, ads_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_ads (user_id, ads_id) values (?, ?)
read
Hibernate: select jwtuser0_.id as id1_1_0_, ads2_.id as id1_0_1_, adsfavouri1_.user_id as user_id1_2_0__, adsfavouri1_.ads_id as ads_id2_2_0__ from jwt_user jwtuser0_ left outer join user_ads adsfavouri1_ on jwtuser0_.id=adsfavouri1_.user_id left outer join ads ads2_ on adsfavouri1_.ads_id=ads2_.id where jwtuser0_.id=?
JwtUser(id=1, adsFavourites=[Ads(id=1), Ads(id=2)])
delete
Hibernate: select jwtuser0_.id as id1_1_0_, ads2_.id as id1_0_1_, adsfavouri1_.user_id as user_id1_2_0__, adsfavouri1_.ads_id as ads_id2_2_0__ from jwt_user jwtuser0_ left outer join user_ads adsfavouri1_ on jwtuser0_.id=adsfavouri1_.user_id left outer join ads ads2_ on adsfavouri1_.ads_id=ads2_.id where jwtuser0_.id=?
Hibernate: select jwtuser0_.id as id1_1_0_ from jwt_user jwtuser0_ where jwtuser0_.id=?
Hibernate: select adsfavouri0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, adsfavouri0_.ads_id as ads_id2_2_0_, ads1_.id as id1_0_1_ from user_ads adsfavouri0_ inner join ads ads1_ on adsfavouri0_.ads_id=ads1_.id where adsfavouri0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: delete from user_ads where user_id=? and ads_id=?
read
Hibernate: select jwtuser0_.id as id1_1_0_, ads2_.id as id1_0_1_, adsfavouri1_.user_id as user_id1_2_0__, adsfavouri1_.ads_id as ads_id2_2_0__ from jwt_user jwtuser0_ left outer join user_ads adsfavouri1_ on jwtuser0_.id=adsfavouri1_.user_id left outer join ads ads2_ on adsfavouri1_.ads_id=ads2_.id where jwtuser0_.id=?
JwtUser(id=1, adsFavourites=[Ads(id=2)])
```

And don't forget:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = "id")
public class Ads {
    ...
}
```